Text display in random position in all other activities of app, by triggering from one activity
I have Main, Home activities are there Launcher app side (.apk). PlayActivity, Profile, and Init are there on the library side (.aar)
from the server side 1 message will trigger, then I want to show that message in PlayActivity until getdisplayperiod is over it has to display in the same position in all other activities if we navigate. Again it has redraw if it is there in PlayActiviy.java in another random position. If it is there in the same activity it has to display till getdisplayperiod and disappear till totalperiod-getdisplayperiod again it has to display. If it is there in another activity after getdisplayperiod there is no need for redraw.
How to achieve a solution for the above problem?
I have tried with overlay, but all Android boards don't have permissions.

When you display the message in Activity A, use a flag like "shouldDisplay = true"; and reset it to false when you close the message. And in onPause of activity A, if "shouldDisplay" is true, either save the flag and remaining time to a sharedpreference file or use an intent. And in activity B's onCreate (or wherever you want) access that sharedpreference file and if the value is true, display the message again / receive the intent and display the message based on the remaining time. Once total time is over, reset the flag to false in sharedpreference file. You can also save content of the message to sharedpreference file / share it via intent if the message isn't static

BTW one thing i don't understand is, if you're displaying the message until "getdisplayperiod" is over, how come the user is able to navigate to another activity? Or do you allow the user to close the message? If you do, then why do you want to show the user the same message when user navigate to another activity? By closing the message, user made it clear they're not interested in the message. Right?

Its security ID keeps displaying the text in all other activities. The trigger point of the text will be activity C (Play). After it is displayed, it has to be there in all other activities like A, B, and D. After disappearing again, it has to be redrawn only in activity C.

While display also it has to navigate from one activity to another activity

@insider_ank Follow the procedure i mentioned earlier. After triggering the text in activity C, based on the time the text was displayed, write "shouldDisplay" true/false to sharedpreference including remaining time. And when user navigate to other activities, access the sharedpreference file and based on the flag show/do not show the text. And if showing, in that activity too track the total time the text was displayed and set it to false in sharedpreference when time's over and if value is false in sharedpreference, show the text in activity C only

Is there any window concept? I will trigger the text view in the C activity, but it to show in all other activities till get the display period while navigating from one activity. Like overlay, but it has permission issues in some of the Android devices.
By following your above method I will not have full control, I think so.

@insider_ank I'm not aware of any overlay approach that can be used in your case. Using my approach you'll have full control. While you show the text in Activity C you just need to count the total time the text was displayed in activity C and if that period is lower than your intended display period, write it to sharedpreference in activity C's onstop. And in other activities, access that file, check the remaining time and show it until that period is over

activity to 'C'  To 'A' is fine. while going from 'A' to 'B'. The positioning of text in the C is random. while navigating to another activity it has to show in the same position.

If you want to show the text in the same position, you should adjust the position of the TextView accordingly. In all your layouts where you want to display the text, reserve a specific position for the textview and initially set it to INVISIBLE and make it VISIBLE when you show the text

It looks like every time redraw the text, is there any Windows concept which does not look like redrawing without any permissions? It has to serve the purpose.

You can try to use a singleton class with windowManager and call the method to show the textview from that class in activity's onResume. Since you've mentioned that your issue is with position of the textview in a particular activity, better you try to give it a fixed position so that other views in the layout wont push it. Looks like it's the easiest fix
